# Output of a double value and differencing with colours

Tags: octave, gnu, octave-gui

I have a CSV file in which one column consists of values (class: double) named `INV_OutputTorque` (89155×1). There are values from -200<x<200 [Nm]. For visualization purposes I want two different colours, one for values of zero and below, and one colour for all other values (positive).

I tried two approaches.

```
generatorisch = find(INV_OutputTorque <=0)
motorisch = find(INV_OutputTorque > 0)
Plot (INV_Speed, generatorisch, 'g.' ,INV_Speed, motorisch, 'r.');
```

results in error because Not same length as `INV_OutputTorque`.

```
If INV_OutputTorque <= 0, plot ('g.');
Else INV_OutputTorque > 0, plot ('r.');
Endif;
```

results in error no data to plot.

How can I make this plot?

Comment: `scatter` has an input argument to specify the color for each point.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `find()` is an array of indexes. Plotting it directly is not meaningful, you have to use it to extract the subarrays you want to plot.

```matlab
generatorisch = find(INV_OutputTorque <=0)
motorisch = find(INV_OutputTorque > 0)
Plot (INV_Speed(generatorisch), INV_OutputTorque(generatorisch), 'g.', ...
      INV_Speed(motorisch),     INV_OutputTorque(motorisch),     'r.');
```